# Swift get all items from URL

Tags: ios, swift

I am making small music player with mp3 ftp steam.

It's how i add my URL's to list:

```
self.playList.add("http://my-ftp.pl/mp3/1.mp3")
self.playList.add("http://my-ftp.pl/mp3/2.mp3")
self.playList.add("http://my-ftp.pl/mp3/3.mp3")
...
self.play(url: URL(string:(playList[self.index] as! String))!)
```

I am searching for any ideas how to get all (*.mp3) URL (http://my-ftp.pl/mp3) folder elements without entering the entire path.

Comment: The link doesn't work, anyway you can make an HTTPUrl request to this url and try to get the entire playlist with a JSON parsification, try to use this cocoa https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire and maybe try to pick up something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, but i made that.

```
 func getMp3() {

        let url = URL(string: "http://not-my-ftp-just-simple.com/mp3")!

        let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, urlResponse, error in
            if let localURL = localURL {
                if let string = try? String(contentsOf: localURL) {

                    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:"href=(.*?)>", options: [])
                    var results = [String]()

                    regex.enumerateMatches(in: string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.utf16.count)) { result, flags, stop in
                        if let r = result?.range(at: 1), let range = Range(r, in: string) {

                            if (String(String(string[range]).toLengthOf(length: 1).dropLast())).contains(".mp3"){
                            results.append(String(String(string[range]).toLengthOf(length: 1).dropLast()))
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    print(results)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get contents of a remote folder , but you can

```
var counter = 1

func getMp3(_ url:URL) {

API.load(url) { (response,data,error) in

   if let data = data { 
      // use data
      coounter += 1
     getMp3(urlWithNewCounter)
   }

}
```